# When trying to update the pods, terminal gives error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode12

When using pod install or update, its giving error, please look at the pod file and logs.
Tried many solutions given in the links of the logs.

target 'Test' do

use_frameworks!

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.2'
pod 'RxSwift', '~> 5'

pod 'RxCocoa', '~> 5'
pod 'RxAlamofire'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
pod 'PINRemoteImage', '~> 3.0.1'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'StatusAlert', '~> 1.1.1'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit'
pod 'MaterialComponents/ActivityIndicator'
pod 'SwiftMessages'
pod 'MaterialComponents/Snackbar'
```

end

#### Error

```
RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.8/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:218:in `initialize_from_file'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.8/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:103:in `open'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:918:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:917:in `each'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:917:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:912:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:78:in `analyze'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/pod:22:in `load'

/Applications/CocoaPods.app/Contents/Resources/bundle/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D+Unknown+object+version.&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

- RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version

  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10432 [closed] [2 comments]

  a day ago
- RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.

  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10259 [closed] [5 comments]

  5 weeks ago
- RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.

  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7697 [closed] [32 comments]

  01 Jan 2021

and 58 more at:

[https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&utf8=✓](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

[!] [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>["${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-Test/Pods-Test-frameworks-${CONFIGURATION}-input-files.xcfilelist"], "outputFileListPaths"=>["${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-Test/Pods-Test-frameworks-${CONFIGURATION}-output-files.xcfilelist"]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa.

If this attribute was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new

[!] [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>["${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-Test/Pods-Test-resources-${CONFIGURATION}-input-files.xcfilelist"], "outputFileListPaths"=>["${PODS_ROOT}/Target Support Files/Pods-Test/Pods-Test-resources-${CONFIGURATION}-output-files.xcfilelist"]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa.

If this attribute was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new

Comment: Do you have Intel chip or M1 chip?

Comment: @Rob i have a intel chip